# Meaning and Correctness of "to have masses said for someone's soul"

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is the meaning of "to have masses said for someone's soul"? I failed to find it in my dictionary. And grammatically, is it correct to say, "to have masses (which are) said for someone's soul"?

Comment: From memory, "Mass" is one of the seven sacraments of Catholicism, and is found in some form in a number of other Christian sects; In practice, it's a particular kind of religious ritual: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_(liturgy)

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. It's perfectly grammatical to request masses to be said for someone/something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mass is a rite of the (usually Catholic) church. The priest who performs it "says mass".

It used to be (and may still be sometimes) that a priest would be asked to perform a mass on behalf of someone who had died, with the intention of benefitting the soul of the deceased person - often of reducing their punishment in the afterlife. If a person requested a number of these then he would "have masses said for [the deceased person]'s soul".

Perfectly grammatically acceptable.

(With apologies to Catholics for the over-simplification of the description of the mass).