# What does "say mass" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

I cannot understand "saying mass" means in the sentence "Pope Francis conferred sainthood on Óscar Romero, an archbishop who was murdered in 1980 while saying mass by an army-backed death squad in El Salvador."? Can anyone help explain it? Thanks!

Comment: The archbishop was officiating/performing the rite of mass. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158377/meaning-and-correctness-of-to-have-masses-said-for-someones-soul

Answer (score 1):

***[Say mass](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mass)*** means celebrate mass in the following sense:

Church cerimony   (also Mass):

> a) [countable, uncountable] the main ceremony in some Christian churches, especially the Roman Catholic Church, which celebrates the last meal that Jesus Christ ate
>
> ***say/celebrate Mass***  (=perform this ceremony as a priest)

(Longman Dictionary)

[image]

Blue Jays, faculty, and staff celebrate Mass in the Chapel of the North American. (Google images)